# Read excel with python

Tags: python, html, excel, regex, dataframe

I have an excel table with 7 columns, linked below:
[Excel Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EID3T.png)

I need to convert each row into the following format as a String: (comma after end bracket)

```
{'symbol': 'A', 'dbeta': 0.75721435, 'cdar_beta': 0.9713204, 'avg_growth': 0.122860, 'drawdown': 0.69207, 'beta': 1.12845, 'u-ratio': 0.643475},
```

I am not able to traverse the excel file in the right way and identify what column I am in. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Note that the "beta" and "u-ratio" are blank in the excel picture but will be filled later.

Comment: Is pandas an option for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first read the file using pandas [`read_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html), then you can transform each row of the dataframe to the desired dict you wish using [`to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) with the following argument `orient='records'`

So all in all:

```
import pandas as pd

with open(<your excel>, 'r') as fp:
    df = pd.read_excel(fp)
df.to_dict(orient='records')
```

Comment: are you able to read the excel file with this? `df = pd.read_excel('my_excel_file.xlsx')`

Comment: @BlackRaven Yes, its also possible. You can look at the docs, it gets: `str, bytes, ExcelFile, xlrd.Book, path object, or file-like object`

Comment: Thanks for the help, but how do I set up the dict to look like the format I need? I am not really familiar with it

Comment: @EeshNaik this `df.to_dict(orient='records')` will give you the format you asked, please review the `to_dict` docs (I supplied the link in my answer)

Comment: @DavidS I tried opening it like this: with open("C:\Users\eeshn\Desktop\AMS 487\10yr_04-01.xlsx", 'r') as fp: but got an error (SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape)

Comment: @EeshNaik try `open(r"C:\Users\eeshn\Desktop\AMS 487\10yr_04-01.xlsx", 'r') as fp:`